# saving XMLHttpRequest.responseText in a variable

Tags: php, javascript

I'm writing a small script in JS to save the data using a php website like this:

```
function getPopulation(id) {
    var xhr_object = null;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) // Firefox
       xhr_object = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if(window.ActiveXObject) // Internet Explorer
       xhr_object = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    else { // XMLHttpRequest non support? par le navigateur
       alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas les objets XMLHTTPRequest...");
       return;
    }

    var url = "http://localhost/inf347/td-svg/population.php?id=1";
    var res = 0;

    xhr_object.open("GET", url,true);
    xhr_object.send(null) ;
    xhr_object.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xhr_object.readyState==4) {
                //alert(xhr_object.responseText) ;
                res =   xhr_object.responseText ;
        }
    }
    alert(res);
    //return -1;
}
```

If I uncomment the line "//alert(xhr_object.responseText) ;" then the program prints the correct answer. But there is no way to save that value into a variable.
Does anyone know how to get round it?

Thanks,
Son

Comment: You need either an event handler function in which you pass the response to it `if (readyState == 4)`, or save it to a global variable then call your event handler function.

Answer (score 2):

"alert(res);" will not work, because browser doesn't wait for AJAX call to complete, it executes the whole script. If you want to act on returned data, you need to add callback in your xhr_object.onreadystatechange function.

```
if (xhr_object.readyState==4) {
    //alert(xhr_object.responseText) ;
    res =   xhr_object.responseText ;

    act_on_response(res);
}
```

Somewhere else in the code:

```
function act_on_response(res)
{
    alert(res);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Is there a way to force getPopulation to wait until the response has arrived? Because what I want is to retrieve the value if `res`, `alert(res)` is just for testing purposes.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest.open() method's third parameter controls whether request is asynchronous or not. If you change your function call to `xhr_object.open("GET", url, false);`, that should make your call synchronous and JavaScript will wait until response is received.

Answer (score 1):

You must give a function name ... se below

```
 if (httpRequest.status == 200) 
                                       responseData(httpRequest);
                                     else
                                       window.status = httpRequest.statusText;      
                                    }
                                  }

  httpRequest.send(zallInOne); 
}

function responseData(dataFromServer) {
  var d = new Date(); 
  document.getElementById("sha1").style.color = "#ff6000";
  document.getElementById("sha1").value = dataFromServer.responseText;
   ...
  ...
 }
```

Comment: Your code example doesn't make a lot of sense. You might fix the formatting, but why are there the extra curly braces?

Answer (score 1):

The `alert` is triggered before the `responseText` has arrived. You can either use a callback function, or move the alert up into the `statechange` function. This is because `getPopulation` starts the `XMLHtpRequest`, but in itself doesn't wait for completion of that and executes everything that's in the function in one go. The `readystatechange` handler listens meanwhile for a trigger to act, but most of the time that trigger occurs after the calling function has executed.

```
// move alert up
if (xhr_object.readyState==4) {
  res =   xhr_object.responseText ;
  alert(res);
}
// use a callback
if (xhr_object.readyState==4) {
  myCallback(xhr_object.responseText);
}
function myCallback(res){
  alert(res);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the response to a properly delcared global variable, or update the content of the document, it should work properly.

I guess the problem is with the last alert line.

```
xhr_object.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xhr_object.readyState==4) {
            //alert(xhr_object.responseText) ;
            res =   xhr_object.responseText ;
    }
}
alert(res); // THIS LINE
```

Note that `onreadystatechange` is a callback function, which means that this function will be called when the response is received. That is, the function is called asynchronously. So the application will continue to execute, and your alert can (will) be executed before the response is received. So you will get an alert which says '0'.